# MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to string failed for value at path for model "User"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I have been trying to figure this out for some hours now trying to search a string passed from postman `{ "firstname": "Tom" }` . I have tried stackoverflow but none seem to solve the issue for me

Whenever I do something like this, I get the object back from the DB

```
  async checkName(name: string) {

            let user = await this.userModel.findOne({"firstname": 'Tom'});
            console.log(user);
}
```

But if I do something like this

```
 async checkName(name: string) {

            let user = await this.userModel.findOne({  "firstname": name });
            console.log(user);
}

> I get this error

name { firstname: 'Tom' }
MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to string failed for value "{ firstname: 'Tom' }" at path "firstname" for model "User"
    at new CastError
```

I am trying to figure out what is wrong and possible solution to this

Comment: `{ firstname: 'Tom' }` is the argument that is being passed as `name` to checkName?

Comment: I discover that this line in register method ```const createdUser = new this.userModel(createDTO);
        var newUser = await createdUser.save();```  createdUser.name and newUser.name are returning undefined. So if I pass createdUser.name as argument. its null.

Comment: But when I log createdUser or newUser, I got the object object back. Why is  createdUser.name and newUser.name returning undefined